# Unable to navigate to URL after passing the URL as argument from a file in Appium & Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, appium-ios

I have been trying to pass the URL after reading from a file, but it always returns me as "url("[object Object]")". Below is what I have tried

```
fs.readFile('./test/testdata/URL.txt','utf-8',(err,data)=>{

        if(err){
            console.error(err)
        }

        console.log('URL':+data);

 browser.execute('mobile: launchApp'{'bundleId':'com.apple.mobilesafari'})

        browser.url(data)

    })
```

When I pass the direct URL , for example: http://www.google.com. It is performing as expected, but is throwing me an error only when I pass the data after reading from file.

URL received after reading file is of "https". I am not sure if this is causing the issue.

Can anyone please help

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after some research, I found the answer to my problem above. For anyone else facing this issue, please follow the below

```
fs.readFile('./test/testdata/URL.txt','utf-8',(err,data)=>{

        if(err){
            console.error(err)
        }

        console.log('URL':+data);

  // Perform this step successfully pass the URL value successfully

 let readurl = JSON.stringify(data) 

 browser.execute('mobile: launchApp'{'bundleId':'com.apple.mobilesafari'})

        browser.url(readurl)

    })
```